# Looping with php over a php-Statement wrapped in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

I am using dygraphs to plot a graph. I am using a database to store all the values i need. to use dygraphs i have to use javascript. but the data im getting from the database needs to fill the dygraphs constructor dynamically. i could do it like this, but that isnt dynamic and not what i need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        g = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById('graphdiv'),
            "Travel(mm),Force(N)\n"+
            "0,0\n"+
            "<?php  $sql = "SELECT daten FROM azubi3 where pau_table_id=2";
                    $result = pg_query($sql);
                    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
                    $toEcho = str_replace("{","[",$row[0]);
                    $toEcho = str_replace("}","]",$toEcho);
                    $toEcho = json_decode($toEcho);
                    echo $toEcho[0][0].','.$toEcho[0][1].'\n';
                    ?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[1][0].','.$toEcho[1][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[2][0].','.$toEcho[2][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[3][0].','.$toEcho[3][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[4][0].','.$toEcho[4][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[5][0].','.$toEcho[5][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[6][0].','.$toEcho[6][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[7][0].','.$toEcho[7][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[8][0].','.$toEcho[8][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[9][0].','.$toEcho[9][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[10][0].','.$toEcho[10][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[11][0].','.$toEcho[11][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[12][0].','.$toEcho[12][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[13][0].','.$toEcho[13][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[14][0].','.$toEcho[14][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[15][0].','.$toEcho[15][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[16][0].','.$toEcho[16][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[17][0].','.$toEcho[17][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[18][0].','.$toEcho[18][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[19][0].','.$toEcho[19][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[20][0].','.$toEcho[20][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[21][0].','.$toEcho[21][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[22][0].','.$toEcho[22][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[23][0].','.$toEcho[23][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[24][0].','.$toEcho[24][1].'\n';?>"+
            "<?php  echo $toEcho[25][0].','.$toEcho[25][1].'\n';?>"
        );

    </script>
```

because i have to seperate the data with "...."+ i dont know how to control that i echo as much as my array is long. i thought of a loop over the javascript code which itself contained php. it didnt work. some ideas? or questions, i dont know if anyone will understand me...

Comment: Use ajax? And then format the data in the php part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a perfect case for using foreach

Output will look like

```
"123,123\n;"+
.....
"126,143\n;"
```

Code:

```
$setCount = 0; // keeps track of sets so i dont put a linebreak before the first one
$toEcho = json_decode($toEcho);
foreach ($toEcho as $set){
  if($setCount>0) echo "+"; // every set is seperated with a plus
  echo "\""; // put double quote down
  $valueCount = 0;
  foreach($set as $value){
    if($valueCount>0) echo ',';
    echo $value;
    $valueCount++;
  }
  echo "\\n;\""; // puts the weird \n into the string and final quote
  $setCount++;
}
```

Let me know if something is unclear.